# Django Rest Framework Arbitrary Relationship Field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-3.5, json-api

I am struggling to find a way to create an arbitrary relationship between two models in Django/Rest Framework.

Consider a table that exists with a primary key, that logs actions permissible by some user or group, the table would look like this:

Auth:
`pk | user | action`

And `pk` is an auto-generated integer.

I need to create a serializer, or non-managed model, that correctly retrieves relationship info, as if it had a foreign key in this table.

The general idea is that a route like this:

`/customauth/test/`

Would produce all the things that user is authorized to do. Keep in mind that just making a custom attribute(s) and populating it with custom querysets in the view will not solve the problem, as I am using JSON-API, which specifically reports things that are relationships as such (so the field must actually be a RelatedField or subclass).

Basically, I need to make a related field (either in serializers or models) that behaves like a completely custom dataset. I provide the relationship based on the queryset, or manually indicate what fields are 'related'.

Here is a sample desired response:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "type":"CustomUserAuthDetailView",
      "id":"test",
      "attributes":{  
         "user":"test"
      },
      "links":{  
         "self":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/test/"
      }
   },
   "relationships":{  
      "auth":{  
         "links":{  
            "self":"/customauth/test/relationships/auth"
         },
         "data":{  
            "type":"auth",
            "id":"1"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The [JSON API plugin](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api) for Django Rest Framework renders this response for me, however, the relationship(s) have to exist, and since I can't use a real relationship (the 'customauth' is an unmanaged table, and actually represents something like Active Directory, which I can't touch, and could potentially have unlimited different values), and the `Auth` table itself is not unique on `user` (and can't be), and this information needs to be consumed by other tables identically, so I can't use `content-type` and a `GenericForeignKey` system. (Content type lets you have multiple foreign relationships, but not per row, just per column... unless I'm misunderstanding it).

I feel like I have to be missing something, as I can't be the only person that wants to accomplish this. I thought about making my own sub class of RelatedField, but have so far not had luck, and while I go down that path, I figured I'd check to see if someone far more experienced than I knew something I'm missing.

Full sample application:

`models.py:`

```
from django.db import models


class Auth(models.Model):

    actions = (("POST", "Create"),
               ("GET", "Retrieve"),
               ("PUT", "Update"),
               ("DELETE", "Remove"))

    user = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=actions)


class CustomUserAuth(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        managed = False

    user = models.CharField(max_length=24, primary_key=True)
```

`serializers.py:`

```
from rest_framework_json_api import serializers
from .models import Auth, CustomUserAuth


class AuthSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Auth
        read_only_fields = ('url', )


class CustomUserAuthSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUserAuth
        fields = ('user', 'url')
```

`views.py:`

```
from rest_framework import views
from .models import CustomUserAuth
from .serializers import CustomUserAuthSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response


class CustomUserAuthDetailView(views.APIView):

    @staticmethod
    def get(request, pk, format=None):
        auth = CustomUserAuth()
        auth.user = pk
        serialized = CustomUserAuthSerializer(
            auth,
            context={"request": request}
        )
        return Response(serialized.data)
```

`urls.py:`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from fake_relationship.views import CustomUserAuthDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^auth/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/$',
        CustomUserAuthDetailView.as_view(),
        name='customuserauth-detail'
    )
]
```

`settings.py:`

```
"""
Django settings for djtest project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'bb@&3)=$3v2wfq+hzg4fihrla+5()dnxdwka35^!@v1xh!b17&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'fake_relationship'
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'rest_framework_json_api.exceptions.exception_handler',
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS':
        'rest_framework_json_api.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_json_api.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_json_api.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'rest_framework_json_api.metadata.JSONAPIMetadata',
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djtest.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djtest.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Can you use Foreign Key in relationship?

Comment: No, the CustomUserAuth table doesn't actually exist, so nothing can have a foreign key to it, and the Auth table's primary key is an auto incrementing integer -- 'user' is not unique, and can't be. No foreign key relationships are possible for these reasons.

Comment: I have the same problem, I need to put a link derived from an object's field into the relationship-section, but the link doesn't point to a table. It's trivially easy with `SerializerMethodField` but then the link is in the wrong part of the JSON structure. I've tried `SerializerMethodResourceRelatedField` and `SerializerMethodHyperlinkedRelatedField` but cannot get any of them to produce a link at all. (The method is run and return a link but the link isn't in the finished json.)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with SerializerMethodField and return anything that you want from there , it basically design for making operation before return value but you can to DataModel and retrieve data

Comment: Unfortunately, SerializerMethodField is not a subclass of RelatedField, so it will not get reported as a relationship in the response.